# Database inheritance performance optimization

Tags: sql, performance, inheritance

Say I have a MySQL DB inheritance design as follow :

```
CREATE TABLE parent
(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  type ENUM('A', 'B')
);

CREATE TABLE child_a
(
  parent_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  a_val TEXT
  -- FK to parent table...
); 

CREATE TABLE child_b
(
  parent_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  b_val TEXT,
  -- FK to parent table...
);
```

Then using the following query :

```
SELECT * FROM parent p
JOIN child_a a ON p.type = 'A' AND a.parent_id = p.id
JOIN child_b b ON p.type = 'B' AND b.parent_id = p.id;
```

My question is: Does adding the type column check as a first condition in the `JOIN` going to stop the DB from actually going through every row of the child_a table if the parent.type is 'B'?

Comment: It should but the optimizer is sometimes unpredictable. But I doubt you will  encounter a speed different if you use it or not

Comment: Well maybe not in this simple design, but in my real application, there's a good amount of child types. And this would be even more relevant if the inheritance had grand children and grand-grand-children, and so on. Then the effects of going through every tables' rows would gets exponential.

Comment: Actually now that I think about it, since IDs are indexed, I would need a ton of child and grandchild tables to notice a real performance gain